A spy lives a happy married life until he finds out their life is staged, the wife finds out he was a spy
I watched this spy movie a few years ago and I'm pretty sure it came out in the 2000s. The name just keeps slipping from my mind, but I remember seeing the actors somewhere before. 
Plot: This spy is in a beachy place, somewhere on holiday. The heroine is here too, with her parents and she's really clumsy. The hero blows up a helicopter early on in the movie, and the two fall in love, get married.
Fast forward, they're living in a nice house, near the heroine's parents, whose father is military, I think.
Then things start to blow up, and they get followed. The heroine finds out he was a spy who quit, and they have comic situations where they almost get killed.
She also finds out she's pregnant somewhere in the middle. Their neighbours also turn out to be plants, and her father turns out to be a spy too. 
The movie ends with a devastated house because of all the fights and safety cameras over their baby's crib.
Other scenes I remember: She ducks under a table in the beginning and explains her dad away as a kidnapper or bad guy or something. She also trips a lot in the early scenes. 
Later on, she's really pissed about finding he's a spy. She walks away from him, and they end up in a car that's not theirs.

Welcome to Movies & TV! We have a minimum standard for ID questions. Please try to add anything that may help identification. What country was it likely from or what language was it in? Descriptions or names of characters or actors you can give? Feel free to [edit] any additional details into the question. For help writing a good identification question, see: Identify-This-X Questions.

I believe this to be the 2010 film Killers starring Ashton Kutcher and Katherine Heigl.
Parts of the Plot from wiki:

After a break-up with a boyfriend, an overcautious Jen (Katherine
  Heigl) travels to Nice, France, with her parents (Tom Selleck and
  Catherine O'Hara). After getting into an elevator to go to her hotel
  room, she meets Spencer Aimes (Ashton Kutcher). Spencer asks her out
  for drinks, and she accepts. The scene then changes to Spencer
  sneaking onto a boat, putting a remote controlled bomb on the bottom
  of a helicopter, then taking out a guard. He then swims back and goes
  on the date with Jen. After the helicopter takes off, Spencer triggers
  the bomb using his phone.
...
A little while later, Jen comes back (without having gone on her trip)
  to find Spencer being tossed around their house by Henry (Rob Riggle),
  Spencer's best friend and co-worker. Spencer screams for her to get
  his gun (of which she was unaware) and she shoots Henry in the arm.
  While interrogating him, Henry reveals that there is a $20 million
  bounty on Spencer's head. An unidentified sniper takes shots at them,
  and Spencer and Jen flee. Henry goes after them; and, after a car
  chase through the neighborhood, they end up in a construction zone,
  where Henry crashes his car. Spencer rams him into a trench, impaling
  his car on rebar and killing him. They then go to the hotel room where
  Spencer's old boss is staying but find that someone has already killed
  him. Jen demands that they go to her Dad for help, but Spencer
  disagrees. In the middle of their argument Jen vomits and declares
  that she might be pregnant.
...
Meanwhile, one assassin, Kristen (Casey Wilson), one of Jen's best
  friends, holds Jen's mother as a hostage in a Mexican standoff with
  Jen. Jen's father arrives and kills Kristen. He then explains that he
  was the one who put out the bounty on Spencer. He knew of Spencer's
  previous work all along, and hired the neighbors and co-workers three
  years before, in case Spencer started working for his old boss again,
  who Jen's father says had "gone dirty." After seeing the postcard from
  Holbrook in Spencer's office, he came to the conclusion that Spencer
  had re-accepted his old job and activated the assassins. He reveals
  that he had been an operative as well, and that he was actually the
  target Spencer was supposed to kill in Nice three years earlier.
In a standoff between Spencer and Jen's father, he does not trust that
  Spencer is really out of the game. Wanting to prove that he really did
  get out, Spencer drops his gun, and tells Jen's father he has no
  intention of killing him. Jen, now convinced, reveals her pregnancy to
  her parents. Jen's father, after killing one last wounded assassin,
  drops his gun as well. The family makes peace by building a trust
  circle, in which Spencer reveals that English is not his first
  language, and that he wanted to be the first one to say "I love you"
  to Jen. The movie ends showing Spencer and Jen's father working on
  some wires near Spencer and Jen's baby's crib. Spencer has grown a
  moustache just like Jen's father. Spencer and Jen then leave to let
  Jen's mom and dad babysit. They all leave the room, but Spencer comes
  back in to activate the lasers protecting the baby.

